# Cannot reach socket server on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, websocket

I am trying to run a socket server on an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance. The socket is able to run just fine on it's own, and telnetting locally on the instance can connect, but trying to telnet to the socket from the outside is failing. I have gone into the security groups to ensure the ports I am using are open for both TCP and UDP (though the socket server has been configured for TCP). Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server might be listening on the loopback interface or ipv6 by default. You can check that by running `netstat --listen -p` which will show you which program listens on which address/port. How to make the program listen on the external ipv4 interface depends on the program/programming language.

Comment: i'm using a php based socket server at the moment for testing, i set it up as a background process and it shows is in the list as listening. as i said in the op, i can connect to it from the local box (ie, ssh to remote machine and telnet there) but cannot from the outside.

Comment: as it turned out i was talking to the loopback. after changing the address i was binding on to the local ip address of the machine things worked just as expected. thanks!